# Can an unhandled exception by one person browsing a site cause a trouble for another simultaneous user?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I'm using ViewState on my ASP.Net site. What will happen if one user's browsing causes an unhandled exception in the application - will that affect another simultaneous user?

Comment: That depends on the exception.

Comment: @SLaks Assuming I'm getting an exception from an msSQL or referencing an object that hasn't been created yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception will terminate that request.

All other requests should not be effected.

Of course, this assumes the normal kind of exception - not like `OutOfMemory` or something that will crash IIS.

Comment: Thanks. But will that exception restart the application? If yes - won't that erase the ViewState?

Comment: @ispiro - It will not restart the application, but the `ViewState` for the page (and session/request) where the exception ends up surfacing will probably be gone.

Comment: @ispiro: No.  And you mean `Session`.

Comment: Actually, I have two buttons, the second which relies on a field which gets some value by the first. So I save that in a `ViewState["myField"]`. So did I understand you correctly that by "where the exception ends up surfacing" you meant - by the user who caused the exception? (And therefore - even if the exception is thrown by personA between the first and second click of personB - the `ViewState` of personB will retain its value)?

Comment: @ispiro - In the _request_ where the exception originated (yes, you can think of this as a specific user).

Answer (score 1):

No.

An exception will terminate the current request, but will not affect the rest of the application.